# How do I make a procedure in scratch for linking the letters to users responses?

Tags: mit-scratch

I am trying to make a hangman game in Scratch for my AP CSP course. I have created a separate sprite for every letter of the alphabet. I want to make it so that when the user tries a letter and it is wrong, that specific letter on the screen will change color. How can I do this with a procedure? Below is my code.
[image]

Comment: Please don't substantially change the question, especially after answers are already offered.

Answer (score 0):

you could make a baking game! This could have many different options of what to make and the player has multiple options. I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The way to communicate between different objects (sprites) is to broadcast a message (as suggested in another answer here, and as you are already doing in your code).

BUT creating 26 different messages (`showc`, `showd`, etc.) is not practical. The idiomatic way of doing it in Scratch is to use a global variable, for example `Letter` and broadcasting a generic message like `ShowLetter`. Then the target sprite can read that `Letter` while processing this message.

Also, having 26 sprites that are doing very similar thing is wrong. I would suggest to have ONE sprite with 26 costumes (for each letter of the alphabet) and clone that sprite for each letter. That way you would need to write `When I receive "message"` only once.

To change a color of a letter, I suggest using `set "color" effect to <number>`. You can play with different numbers to get wht you like.